# 8086 Write a program that takes one string from the input and inserts white space between every two letters

Tags: nasm, x86-16, dosbox

8086 Write a program that takes one string from the input and inserts white space between every two letters

using nasm and MSDOS

i have do following code but it is not working

```
start:        

    mov ax,data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax   
    mov cx, size;cx will contain size,we need it to
                ; check if we have got 10 inputs from key board

    lea dx, Enter_string;it will display a text on screen to enter text
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    call get_string;input string from keyboard

    mov ax, 4ch;terminating 
    int 21h   

get_string: 
     mov si, 0; si will be used as index           
     mov bx, offset string
   get_char: 

     mov ah, 1; get a char from keyboard
     int 21h                                                   

     mov [bx][si], al; saving input in string
     inc si
     cmp si,cx;if si=7 than, no need to take more input
     jne get_char
ret
```

Comment: Not working how?  It looks like it won't even assemble with no definition of the `Enter_string` symbol.  (Or in NASM syntax, not even if there was a definition.  Use `mov dx, Enter_string`, because `lea dx, [Enter_string]` is pointlessly slower / larger, and is still 16-bit absolute addressing.)  Anyway, this is not a [mcve].  Also, if this is a DOS `.com` program, you need `org 0x100`, and `mov ax, data` doesn't look right.  I think you need some other syntax to get the segment base.

Comment: One obvious problem, even going from ancient memories: `mov ax, 4ch`. The `4c` needs to go in AH, with the value you're going to return in AL--but as it stands now, this is putting `4c` in AL, and `00` in AH. I don't recall DOS defining a function 0, so I'm not sure what this will do as it stands now (but almost certainly **won't** terminate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. You should prefer the simplicity of .COM programs while learning. They already start with all the segment registers pointing to the program.
. The DOS exit function expects the function number in `AH`.
. On NASM you don't use `mov bx, offset string`. Just write `mov bx, string`.
. It's easy to combine the tasks of *inputting a string* and *interjecting space characters*. See below code:

```
org 256               ;.COM programs have CS=DS=ES=SS

start:

mov cx, size          ;cx will contain size,we need it to
                      ; check if we have got 10 inputs from key board

mov dx, Enter_string  ;it will display a text on screen to enter text
mov ah, 9
int 21h

call get_string       ;input string from keyboard

mov ax, 4C00h         ;terminating 
int 21h   

get_string:
 push cx
 mov si, 0            ; si will be used as index           
get_char:
 mov ah, 1            ; get a char from keyboard
 int 21h                                                   
 mov ah, " "
 mov [string+si], ax  ; saving input in string PLUS THE SPACE CHARACTER
 add si, 2
 dec cx               ;if si=7 than, no need to take more input
 jnz get_char
 pop cx
 ret
```

Remember that you don't actually need the last space character. Just overwrite it with the string terminator that you normally would add to this string!